# MvvmCross: Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>() return Activity null

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

In my DialogService, after switching to version 8.0 of MvvmCross, Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve() returns me an Activity null.
What am I wrong and what changes compared to version 7.0. ??

Answer (score 0):

It's also happen to me when doing Acr.UserDialogs plugin initialization. This is what I do to solve this problem:

From:

```
UserDialogs.Init(() => Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity);
```

I change it to:

```
UserDialogs.Init(this);
```

I hope my answer can solve your problem, good luck!